# Is there a concept with the requirements for a std::allocator<>-conformant class?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Imagine you'd write an own container-class. And you'd put some C++20 constaints on the allocator. Is there a concept which tests for alle the parts of a std::allocator<>-conformant class ?

Answer (score -1):

There is no trait or concept that fits. So I wrote my own concept that adheres to the parts an allocator needs according to C++20:

```
template<typename Alloc, typename T = typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::value_type>
concept allocator_concept =
    requires( typename Alloc::size_type size )
    {
        { size } -> std::convertible_to<std::size_t>;
    }
    &&
    requires( typename Alloc::value_type value )
    {
        { value } -> std::convertible_to<T>;
    }
    &&
    requires()
    {
        { Alloc() } noexcept;
    }
    &&
    requires( Alloc const &b )
    {
        { Alloc( b ) } noexcept;
    }
    &&
    requires( Alloc a, std::size_t n )
    {
        { a.allocate( n ) } -> std::convertible_to<T *>;
    }
    &&
    requires( Alloc a, T *p, std::size_t n )
    {
        { a.deallocate( p, n ) };
    };
```